# Cannot save objects with references outside their own stores, background and main context issue

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a core data store. What I want is to perform saves in a background context, and fetches on the main context. So I have the following setup of `CoreDataStack` that handles the saving/fetching in the core data:

```
class CoreDataStack {
  static let modelName = "Model"

  static let managedObject: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    guard let modelUrl = Bundle.module.url(
      forResource: "Model",
      withExtension: "momd"
    ) else {
      return .init()
    }
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelUrl) ?? .init()
  }()

  lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(
      name: Self.modelName,
      managedObjectModel: Self.managedObject
    )

    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    dispatchGroup.enter()

    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
      if let error = error as NSError? {
        print("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
      }
      dispatchGroup.leave()
    })

    dispatchGroup.wait()

    return container
  }()

  lazy var backgroundContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    let context = persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()
    context.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy.mergeByPropertyObjectTrump
    return context
  }()

  lazy var mainContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    let mainContext = persistentContainer.viewContext
    mainContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    mainContext.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy.mergeByPropertyObjectTrump
    return mainContext
  }()

  func fetch<Item: NSManagedObject>(
    _ request: NSFetchRequest<Item>
  ) -> [Item] {
    do {
      let items = try self.mainContext.fetch(request)
      return items
    } catch let error as NSError {
      print("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
      return []
    }
  }

  func saveContext() {
    backgroundContext.perform {
      do {
        try self.backgroundContext.save()
      } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have an `NSManagedObject` called `ManagedBar`. This contains a `data` property which is an `NSSOrderedSet` of another `NSManagedObject` called `ManagedFoo`.

I have a function `saveFoo(_:)` which creates a `ManagedFoo` on the background context, requests a `ManagedBar` in the foreground context, then if that `ManagedBar` exists, adds it to the `ManagedFoo` to `data`. Then the background context is saved:

```
func saveFoo(_ Foo: Foo) {
  let managedFoo = ManagedFoo(
    context: coreDataStack.backgroundContext,
    name: foo.name,
  )

  let request = ManagedBar.fetchRequest()
  request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", foo.name)

  if let bar = coreDataStack.fetch(request).first {
    bar.addToData(managedFoo)
  } else {
    let event = ManagedBar(
      context: self.coreDataStack.backgroundContext,
      name: foo.name
    )
    self.coreDataStack.saveContext()
  }
}
```

I also have a function to retrieve all the `name` properties of `ManagedBar` which fetches them all from the main context:

```
func getAllBarNames() -> [String] {
  let fetchRequest = ManagedEvent.fetchRequest()
  let eventData = coreDataStack.fetch(fetchRequest)
  let names = eventData.map { $0.name }
  return names
}
```

Then, when I run the following code, it works most of the time but sometimes fails:

```
func testGetAllEventNames() {
  let foo1 = Foo()
  saveFoo(foo1)

  let foo2 = Foo()
  saveFoo(foo2)


  let names = getAllBarNames()
  print(names)
}
```

This sometimes works fine, but other times fails for one of two reasons:

1. `Cannot save objects with references outside their own stores.`
2. `Collection <__NSCFSet: 0x6000031407b0> was mutated while being enumerated.` (this occurs on the second `saveFoo`)

Other times, `names` doesn't contain all the names that I've saved. These errors happen even if I run this code in a unit test and wait for the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSave` notification before calling `getAllBarNames()`

This must be caused by some background/main context issue but not entirely sure what. Does anyone know what's going wrong here?

Comment: You are mixing objects from different contexts in your save method, make sure you fetch from the background context as well. Easiest solution is to pass the managed context as an argument to the fetch function

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Just did as you suggested and seems to have worked! thanks